# Converting long table to list with parent-child relationship

Tags: r, networkd3

Here is input.

```
ID  Element
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   A
2   D
2   E
2   B
3   B
3   D
```

Expected output would look similar to what this code produces

```
URL <- paste0(
        "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
        "master/JSONdata//flare.json")

## Convert to list format
Flare <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)

# Use subset of data for more readable diagram
Flare$children = Flare$children[1:3]
```

So for first element A is parent of B, C is parent of B, for second A is parent of D, D is parent of E, E is parent of B.
I tried to use `data.tree` package, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: So what kind of object do you want to create?

Comment: Is this supposed to be hierarchical data (like the flare data)? If so, how can both A and E be the parent of B?